# how can I create maven Gwt project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt

Hello friends I have not so much Idea about maven build tool. I just download and install it in my system as I read maven is a build tool and work perfectly with transitive dependency. this is the basic reason to use it

I also configure mavan plugin in Eclipse.

so what is the proper Gwt maven archetype in eclipse and I read so many command in tutorials like maven:gwt run but I dont to where is this command exist in eclipse

I am very new in maven so please help me like a beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common approach to get support of `maven` in existing `GWT-Project`

> 1. Make a gwt project by using the gwt plugin in Eclipse. Now you have
>      an Eclipse gwt project.
> 2. Select the project in Project Explorer , right-click it, then choose
>          Configure . Then select Convert to Maven Project . Now you get a
>          gwt-maven project.
> 3. Now add necessary dependencies to pom.xml .

if you want to create a `gwt maven` project directly you need to choose `gwt archetype` if not exist you can add this have a look in 
[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QPOAXLGB2Y)

Comment: this video is really help full but could you tell me about configure existing GWT project

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Download the gwt plugin in Eclipse and create a gwt project.
2. In Eclipse select the project, right-click on it, then choose `Configure`. Then select `Convert to Maven Project`.

Now you get a gwt-maven project.

Comment: if I create a GWT project with existing command webAppCreator and then convent it in maven . will it work ?

Comment: in some tutorial i read we can directly create a maven project with GWT support .

Comment: actually I have a project which is create by gwt command if I configure it will work are you sure ?